# What kind of glass glue can replace silicone?

Tags: equipment

I tried to put the 'Ferrofluid' and the clear liquid in a large glass tank.
My glass tank was bonded with silicone. However, silicon reacted with 'Ferrofluid' ('Ferrofluid' became sticky and hardened).
Perhaps 'Ferrofluid' seems to have chemically reacted with silicon because 'heptane' is the base.
What kind of glass glue can replace silicone?
Perhaps the epoxy is good, but it is not elastic.

[image]

Comment: how big a tank do you need? 10x17 inches ok?

Comment: picture is just a sample.
Actually I want to make 65 x 65 x 3 inch.

Comment: Wow. I want to see this when it's done ;) So, your requirements are basically a material that will maintain the structural integrity of this glass tank filled with heptane, but that will not interact with your ferrrofluid? What is the ferrofluid material?

Comment: https://youtu.be/RtDdCWEuDwo 
This video is a prototype.
I will only expand its size.
Ferrofluid is composed of nanoparticle size iron powder, surfactant, heptane and so on.
The transparent liquid consists of water, alcohol and so on.